# SQL query to find all values in a table that contain all vowels.

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the first week I have ever worked with SQL. It's rather straightforward and has been fairly easy to pick up.

I had to write a query to find all countries that contain all the vowels ('aeiou') and no white spaces in their name. The only country that fit this criteria was Mozambique.

```
SELECT
  name 
FROM 
  world 
WHERE 
  name LIKE '%a%' AND name LIKE '%e%' AND name LIKE '%i%' AND name LIKE       
 '%o%' AND name LIKE '%u%' AND name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

The above query worked. I wanted to now if there was a way to shorten this, so I could use one LIKE statement and check if the word contained all of those letters in it's name without order mattering.

Comment: Your method is probably the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can do that like so:

```
    SELECT w.name
    FROM world AS w
    WHERE w.name SIMILAR TO '%(a|e|i|o|u)%' 
      AND w.name NOT SIMILAR TO '% %';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other options but nothing much shorter. A couple examples below.

```
...WHERE LOCATE('a',name) AND LOCATE('e',name) ...

...WHERE name REGEXP 'a' AND name REGEXP 'e' ...
```

([mysql 5.7 pattern matching documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) may help too)